# How do I pull a value from column with XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

Hello I have a table called KNXRUNHISTORY and I am trying to pull data from a column called RUNSUMMARYTXT.

The data stored in this column is in xml format.
I am trying to pull the values for these two fields
(entry key="Link1.@OutputType@) and 
(entry key="Link6.@SourceRecordsProcessed@)

Any help would be appreciated as I have banging my head against the wall on this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM 
http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">  
<properties>  
<comment>Comment</comment> 
<entry key="@InterfaceErrorCount@">0</entry>  
<entry key="Link3.@LinkElapsedTime@">0:00:21</entry>  
<entry key="Link1.@OutputType@">4</entry>  
<entry key="Link6.@SourceRecordsProcessed@">148</entry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to use **xpath query** to xml data. But in your case there are some pitfalls.
1. Your data aren't xml data type. Most probably data type of the column in `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`. It would be OK but
2. You have `<!DOCTYPE` declaration which requires conversion [with with style equals to 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Encoding must be `utf-16` (yours is `utf-8`). So encoding in the xml declaration must be fixed or just removed.
Here is working example.

```
declare @tbl table (id int, prop nvarchar(max))
insert @tbl(id,prop) values(1,
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>  
<comment>Comment</comment> 
<entry key="@InterfaceErrorCount@">0</entry>  
<entry key="Link3.@LinkElapsedTime@">0:00:21</entry>  
<entry key="Link1.@OutputType@">4</entry>  
<entry key="Link6.@SourceRecordsProcessed@">148</entry></properties>')

;with cte as(
select id, convert(xml,
     replace( prop,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>',''),--sanitize data
     2 --Enable limited internal DTD subset processing
) x --and then convert to xml data type
from @tbl
)
select t.v.value('entry[@key="Link1.@OutputType@"][1]','int') outputtype,
t.v.value('entry[@key="Link6.@SourceRecordsProcessed@"][1]','int') srcrecprocessed
from cte cross apply x.nodes('properties') t(v) -- use xpath query
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Kenh426 It is good idea to accept the answer when it helps you.

Comment: Sorry...new to this.